# Multi-conditional if/else filter using tidyverse in R

Tags: r, if-statement, filter, tidyverse

I would like to conditionally filter based on multiple conditions.  I've seen many posts on this website that use `if`/`else` conditions for a filter, but never one with multiple conditions inside a single `if` statement.

Take the following sample data as an example:

```
data <- structure(list(names = c("Mike", "Mike", "Sam", "Sam", "Sam", 
"Emma", "Jessica", "Jessica"), tries = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 
3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

data
        names tries
1    Mike     1
2    Mike     2
3     Sam     3
4     Sam     2
5     Sam     2
6    Emma     3
7 Jessica     1
8 Jessica     3
```

In this specific example, I want to take the first and maybe the second row of each grouped name.  I only want to keep the first row for a name if the number of tries is greater than 1.  But, if the number of tries is equal to 1 then I want to keep the first two rows.

I have a workaround that technically does the job, but it doesn't seem like it should work.  Here is my workaround:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  group_by(names) %>% 
  filter(
    if (row_number() == 1 & tries > 1) {
      row_number() == 1
    } else {
      row_number() == 1 | row_number() == 2
    }
  )
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   names [4]
  names   tries
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 Mike        1
2 Mike        2
3 Sam         3
4 Emma        3
5 Jessica     1
6 Jessica     3
Warning messages:
1: In if (row_number() == 1 & tries > 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (row_number() == 1 & tries > 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (row_number() == 1 & tries > 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

You can see that it does return the correct dataset, but it gives me tons of warnings and says that since there are multiple conditions inside the `if` statement then it will only use the first element.  But, it seems like it is using both elements.  Am I missing something here?  Is there a `tidyverse` solution to this problem that avoids the warning messages?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you looked at `case_when()`?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's a bit unclear what you mean whey you say the "number of tries is equal to 1" when they have multiple rows. Does that just mean the first try is equal to 1, or any of their tries are equal to one? You can do

```
data %>% 
  group_by(names) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==1 | (row_number()==2 & first(tries)==1))
```

Note the `if` is implied by the `filter()` expression. This just checks where it's the first row in the group, or (`|`) if it's the second row and (`&`) the first value of `tries` was a 1.

Comment: To improve on the answer, can you elaborate on the function of `|` and `&` for OP?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(names) %>% filter(if(tries[1] > 1) row_number() == 1 else row_number() == 1:2 )
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   names [4]
  names   tries
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 Mike        1
2 Mike        2
3 Sam         3
4 Emma        3
5 Jessica     1
6 Jessica     3
```